# How to send data to ports of client system?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application, that i want to connect it to POS ( Point of sale) device, and send payable price to pos and then pos send back me the result. 
I want to run these operations on client system. how can i send data to ports of client system?

Comment: Care to show what research you have done so far?

Comment: @Darem I highly doubt SingalR has *any* applicability here. OP probably wants to post over a TCP/UDP port, heavens forbid it be some COM port.

Comment: @TanveerBadar oh sorry I delete my comment. Thx for the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I had the same problem. your web application can't communicate with the port directly.

To do that you have to do the following :

1-Create a windows service project

2-Host a web Api in windows service ([Web API Self-Hosting Using Windows Service](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/web-api-self-hosting-using-windows-service/))

That way your web application can call web api hosted in windows service, because web api is listening to the incoming requests. in web api, you can communicate with your desired port directly and send the result to the client.

Finally, to use this feature in your web application you have to prepare a batch file(**it runs your windows service**) of your windows service project and put it in the download section of your website.

if any user wants to use POS( Point of sale)  device have to install the bat file